# Mixins in Angular 2 CLI Sass

Tags: angular, compass-sass, angular-cli

I installed Angular 2 CLI with the setup of SCSS. It now uses scss when generating components and I am give in a style.scss file in the root of my src directory... PERFECT, READY TO GO

But, in my components.scss I want to use some mixens like Breakpoint and Susy.  When I use the import statement such as:

```
@import "~susy";
@import "~breakpoint";
```

In then use these mixins within the compoent.scss, such as:

```
@include container;

or 

@include span(12 of 12);
```

I get an error saying that container cannot be found.

Its like the cli tool won't compile the main style.scss mixins so my components.scss can us it? How on earth am I suppose to ge tthe CLI tool to use it.

Seems so weird that a true purpose of SASS (mixins) is not easily usable or configured out of the box.

Remember, I preset this app to use SCSS, my angular-cli.json should be all set and ready to go.